# EnvDTE.CodeNamespace members are empty?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to find a function in active document however I am struggling with a problem, when the function is inside of a namespace, my code is trying to get the members of the EnvDTE.CodeNamespace object but it returns empty, I tried Children too but it was empty too.

http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/MZ2006009.aspx

My code is generally C# implementation of this code. It struggles at ;

```
If TypeOf objCodeElement Is EnvDTE.CodeNamespace Then
   colCodeElements = CType(objCodeElement, EnvDTE.CodeNamespace).Members
```

this function returns empty CodeElements. Any idea how to solve it?

P.S: My extension runs on C++ files.

Edit: Posting the test codes.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Header.h"
namespace ns_deneme{
    int zaza::func_deneme(int k)
    {
        a = k;
        return a;
    }
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    xaxa a;
    int ba = a.deneme2(5);
}

int xaxa::deneme2(int a){
    return a;
}
```

Header.h

```
namespace ns_deneme{
    class zaza{
        private:
            int a;
            int func_deneme(int k);
    };
}

class xaxa{
public:
    int deneme2(int a);
};
```

Problem is that it does find the functions of wmain and deneme2 at cpp file (header file also not working it gives something like -over range etc.-) but also deneme from cpp file isn't working either.

Comment: The code from the link works for me. Can you post minimal C++ file you have problem with? What is your Visual Studio version?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov sure, sorry for lateness, I didn't check anything work related at weekend. Editing the question now.

Comment: I can now reproduce the problem with the C++ code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend a different way to get current function:

```
    EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
    if (ts == null)
        return;
    EnvDTE.CodeFunction func = ts.ActivePoint.CodeElement[vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction]
                as EnvDTE.CodeFunction;
    if (func != null)
      System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(func.FullName);
```